# Using Json Data in hashmap , For exact reference to json Array data .And using it as a string array for numberpicker

Tags: java, android, json, hashmap

I am working on android application and using number picker for displaying data.
I have this json as a string:

```
{"Acura": ["CL", "ILX", "Integra", "Legend", "MDX", "NSX", "RDX", "RL", "RLX", "RSX", "SLX", "TL", "TLX", "TSX", "Vigor", "ZDX", "Other Acura Models"],
            "Alfa": ["164", "4C", "8C Competizione", "Giulia", "GTV-6", "Milano", "Spider", "Stelvio", "Other Alfa Romeo Models"],
            "AMC": ["Alliance", "Concord", "Eagle", "Encore", "Spirit", "Other AMC Models"],
            "Aston": ["DB11", "DB7", "DB9", "DBS", "Lagonda", "Rapide", "Rapide S", "V12 Vantage", "V8 Vantage", "Vanquish"]} .
```

What I was trying get the object like, Acura, Alfa, AMC, Aston, in single arraylist. I was stuck how to get Acura models in another numberpicker ,
there I need to pass string array of data .

So this was my ambiguous situation.

Now what I need is, I have objects string array so that whenever I pick Acura, the other picker should show Acura models.

If I select Alfa, other picker shows Alfa models. For this I think I need to have hashmap. Still I am unaware how to implement that, if someone can help me out this situation. Thanks.

Comment: HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> ? You just have to use it with Gson. Pretty simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to store your data in a `Map<String,List<String>>`  like this

```
 Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, List<String>>>() {}.getType();
 Map<String, List<String>> source = new Gson().fromJson('your_json_string_here', mapType);
```

and then iterate over it like this :

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : source.entrySet()) {

            String key = entry.getKey();
            List<String> values = entry.getValue();

            //Here you can write your code to do whatever you want
        }
```

Comment: how do i store it , i have single json string ..?

Comment: i want to store data in this  HashMap<String,ArrayList> carsDATA = new HashMap<>();

Comment: you need to parse it with gson i will edit the answer to give you the code

Comment: if this answer you question please upvote my comment and accept it as the right answer